# AutoCADの機能について

Tags: autocad

AutoCADについての質問です。
AutoCAD2018でモデルタブで作業する時、どんどん画層増えていき作業したい画面にするのが大変です。

増えていく画層の中で、現在表示して作業している何個かの画層だけを登録して(例えば天伏図を作図する時は、０画層、Defpoint画層、躯体画層、通り芯画層、天井画層、寸法画層、照明器具画層、文字画層で構成)、他の作業(床伏図等)をしていても一発で構成を登録した画面になるような機能はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「画層プロパティ管理」で右クリック→「画層状態を保存・復元」
これで現在の画層の表示状態を名前付きで保存したり、復元することができます。